# How do I use a JSON array from a ConfigMap as a parameter in my Argo workflow?

Tags: kubernetes, argoproj

I'm trying to read a list of urls stored as Json in a ConfigMap and then pass these as parameters to the next step in my Argo workflow.

My config map looks like this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: urls
data:
  urls: |
    [
      {"url": "https://www.google.com/"},
      {"url": "https://stackoverflow.com/"}
    ]
```

And my workflow template looks like this (metadata omitted for brevity):

```
  templates:
  - name: main
    dag:
      tasks:

      - name: get-urls
        template: urls

      - name: url-thingy
        dependencies: ['get-urls']
        templateRef: 
          name: do-thing-with-the-urls
          template: url-thing
        arguments:
          parameters: 
          - name: url
            value: "{{ item.url }}"
        withParam: "{{tasks['get-urls'].outputs.result}}"

  - name: urls
    resource:
      action: get
      manifest: |
        apiVersion: v1
        kind: ConfigMap
        metadata:
          name: urls
    outputs:
      parameters:
      - name: urls
        valueFrom:
          jsonPath: '{.data.urls}'
```

This loads the ConfigMap file and I can see the urls listed out in the `get-urls` step under outputs. When it tries to execute the `url-thingy` step tho it fails with the message:

```
withParam value could not be parsed as a JSON list: {{tasks['get-urls'].outputs.result}}: invalid character '{' looking for beginning of object key string
```

I feel like I'm close to the solution, but I'm not sure where I'm going wrong? Is withParam the right way of accessing my list?

Comment: I think square-bracket index notation is only valid for expression templates (`{{= whatever }}`). Try this: `{{tasks.get-urls.outputs.result}}`

Answer (score 0):

try `{{=toJson(tasks['get-urls'].outputs.result)}}`

Comment: Thanks @edward-rosinzonsky for the answer. However, this gives me "Skipped, empty params" so it's not quite working as intended.

Comment: withParams expects a JSON list, so your data needs to be in JSON format. You only need withParams if you want to start multiple pods in parallel. If you're just looking to pas the data to the next step, use `arguments: parameters`

Comment: I'm looking to start pods in parallel. That's why the data is in a list. Each item in the json list will be passed to the next process, hence the reason I use `item.url`.